# Microsoft IME - Japanese candidates list getting - C++ example

Tags: c++, input, methods, ime

I need to convert the Japanese characters (Hiragana) to candidates list (Kanji). I don't want to use build-in functionalities like menus etc. - the input will be provided as the string, the output - set of the strings (or structure etc.).

I heard about the Microsoft IME. Looks like it may provide the functionality which I need - unfortunately I see a lot of examples related to using it as built-in system feature instead of sample code which we can use as part of the application.

So - I'm not sure where to start. From my point of view, it should be enough to use single interface. I found https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751984(v=vs.85).aspx - but looks like the IActiveIME is pure virtual class and it will probably require some WinAPI related stuff.

Comment: IMO ImeConversionList() is pretty easy (easier...) to use (it's what COM object calls). One doubt: from the same Hiragana text you may get multiple Kanji results (candidates...), how do you suppose to pick one of them without user interaction?

Comment: Multiple results will be not a problem - I will create own UI.

Comment: Looks like using the [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318649(v=vs.85).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318649(v=vs.85).aspx) will be easier but I'm not sure what's the correct order of the interfaces usage.
So: ImmCreateContext -> ImmSetCompositionString -> ImmSetConversionStatus -> ImmGetCandidateListCount -> ImmGetCandidateList Did I miss something?